# JQuery placing elements X pixels by degree

Tags: jquery, css, trigonometry

Essentially I want to place an element X pixels from the current position towards the center. Here's my code:

```
var sitX = parseInt($('div.par[id='+my+']').css("left"))+43; //43 is half the width
var sitY = parseInt($('div.par[id='+my+']').css("top"))+43; //43 is half the height
var deltaY = sitY - 200; //200 is the vertical center of the screen
var deltaX = sitX - 380; //Same for the horizontal
ang1 = Math.atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;
...
```

I later create it with `right=(Math.cos(ang1)*60)` and `top=(Math.sin(ang1)*60)` on an element with absolute positioning.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to add a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It helps us answer your question with a living example.

Comment: do you have a `position` set? like `position: absolute`

Comment: Yes I do, I've said that already.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgfVR/1/

Comment: Still looking for the damn answer...